# Function printing extra name

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return-value

i'm doing a practice problem where you randomly generate a number between 1-100, and it iterates 100 times then it ether tells the user if the number generated is prime or not. I believe i answered the question except its printing an extra line. I'm not sure if i'm being picky, because the program runs correctly even with the flaw. But i do feel like i should understand why its happening. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import random

def main():
    number=random_number()
    prime_numbers(number)

def random_number():
    for number in range(100):
        number = random.randint(1,101)
        print(number,' ',end='')
        prime_numbers(number)
    return number



def prime_numbers(number):

    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('Not prime')
    else:
        print('Prime')
    return number
main()

 output:
 # I shortened the output for times sake it 
 # iterates 100 times. but the last line is how it 
 # prints.

30  Not prime
36  Not prime
11  Prime
11  Prime
40  Not prime
.
.
.
.
78  Not prime
67  Prime
80  Not prime
78  Not prime
90  Not prime
Prime       <------ not sure where this is coming 
                    from
```

Comment: Inside of `main()`, You call `random_number()` which iterates the requisite times and prints in-line like you want and returns a single number. Then you call `prime_numbers(number)` on that single returned number, which has its own print statement, giving you that extra line. What's the expected behavior of calling a function that calls another, then calling the other function one more time?

Comment: A different issue, function `prime_numbers` is only detecting whether the number is even or odd, not prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice given and corrected my algorithm to not just calculate even/odd numbers . And it works great! Please let me know how i can make this any better as i'm learning.

```
import random

def main():
    for number in range(100):
        number = gen_random()
        prime_numbers(number)


def gen_random():
    number = random.randint(1,101)
    print(number,'', end='')
    return number

def prime_numbers(number):

    is_prime = True

    for y in range (2,number):
        if number % y == 0:
            is_prime=False

    if is_prime == True:
        print("Prime")
    else:
        print("Not Prime")

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling two functions in your main() function

1. `number = random_numbers()` 
   This this generates 100 numbers by looping 100 times and then returns the last number generated which is assigned to your variable **number**. In this function something like `30  Not prime` is printed 100 times.
2. `prime_numbers(number)`
   The last number generated by the `random_numbers()` is assigned to the  variable  **number** which is passed to the function `prime_numbers(number)`.
   This prints the last line **Prime** or **Not Prime**

There is no need calling the `prime_numbers(number)` function again.
Calling the `random_numbers()` function alone solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you're making the call to `prime_numbers()` in both `main()` and `random_number()`, so after `random_number()` iterates 100 times, it outputs its result which is fed into `prime_numbers()` again, even though that number has already been evaluated.

The simplest fix would be to get rid of the call in `main()`, so it would look like this:

```py
def main():
    number=random_number()
```

However, I think it looks cleaner, and makes more sense in the context of your function names to move the iterator into `main()`, so that `random_number()` is responsible only for generating + printing a random number, `prime_numbers()` is only responsible for determining + printing if a number is prime, and `main()` orchestrates the main idea of the program. With this your code would looks like the following:

```py
import random

def main():
    for number in range(100):
        number = random_number()
        prime_numbers(number)


def random_number():
    number = random.randint(1,101)
    print(number,' ',end='')
    return number


def prime_numbers(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print('Not prime')
    else:
        print('Prime')
    return number

main()
```

There are other improvements that can be made here and there, but I hope this at least answers your main question!

Comment: and as mentioned in the comments above by @DarrylG, `prime_numbers()` is only checking whether the input is even/odd